# Loopback custom role based ACL not working

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am using Loopback 3 and my datasource is MySQl. I have created a user with SUPER_ADMIN role. The entries in the table look like below:

The user table looks like below:

```
1   admin   password admin@admin.com
```

The Role table looks like below:

```
3   ADMIN   super admin 4/24/18 11:42 AM    4/24/18 11:42 AM
```

The Rolemapping table

```
4   ADMIN   1   3
```

But when I try use this role in the ACL, it does not work:

```
{
  "accessType": "*",
  "principalType": "ROLE",
  "principalId": "ADMIN",
  "permission": "ALLOW",
  "property": "greet"
}
```

The above always throws 401, Authorization Required error.

Could anyone let me know, if I am missing anything here.

Thanks

Comment: post your debug strings https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Setting-debug-strings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`principalType` value is wrong in the `RoleMapping` entry, `ADMIN` should be replaced with `USER`, which is a constant here: `app.models.RoleMapping.USER`

Comment: Thanks Antonio ! after logging the query, found that it requires 'USER' instead of actual role in the rolemapping table. Replaced the roles with 'USER' and it works find. Thanks @icecream_hobbit.

Comment: No problem. It would be very nice if you also upvote my answer. Thanks.